# how to change radio field style

Tags: sencha-touch, radio-button, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am creating a radio field and it gives me a check box kind for selecting. I want to have a standard radio field with the circle and the dot.

Can anyone help me?

the code used is

```
{
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    ui:'plain',
                    name: 'sendDoc',
                    value: 'Default',
                    label: 'Default',
                    labelWidth: '50%',
                    checked:true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    name: 'sendDoc',
                    id:'workset',
            //      ui:'radio',
                    value: 'Source Workstep',
                    label: 'Source Workstep',
                    labelWidth: '50%'
                    //disabled:true

        }
```